# Set Jenkins slave local area connection to IP address from Jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, slave

Is there a way to set Jenkins slave local area connection to IP address from Jenkins master. I have found code to read the IP address, but I would like to set it.

This is the code I found to read the IP address:

```
import hudson.model.Computer.ListPossibleNames
def node = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNode( "nodeName" )
println node.computer.getChannel().call(new ListPossibleNames())
```

I have looked into `setChannel()` but could not find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Java, and for that matter Groovy, itself is not designed to handle, i.e. change, such low-level things like IP addresses. The lowest you can handle from the [`java.net` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) is a [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

See als this [table of the TCP/IP model](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetprotokollfamilie#TCP.2FIP-Referenzmodell). (It's in German but the examples, in column "Beispiel", should make it clear nevertheless.)